# How to dynamically code collection name inside a function?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to code a Python function to insert my CSV file to MongoDB database using MongoClient() but I don't know how to dynamically code the collection name. Here is my code:

```
def write_toDB(file_name, my_key):
    ...
    db.file_name.insert_one(data)
```

If I write my code like above, the collection name will be "file_name" instead of the parameter file_name. Anyone knows how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: You need something like `db.insert_one(data, file_name)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your comment! I tried it like you suggested but it gave me an error  message saying Collection object is not callable.

Comment: Well, without seeing what your `db` is, it is not possible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the collection using this format:

```
def write_toDB(file_name, my_key):
    ...
    db[file_name].insert_one(data)
```